# Custom JMeter number of iterations per request

Tags: jmeter

Suppose that there's a request set, composed of requests A and B, used as a **set up** for a business case and there is the request that **should be measured** C.

Is there a way to tell JMeter to run A and B requests only once, and C as many times as defined by Thread group or Ultimate group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run once either put A,B in [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)

> A special type of ThreadGroup that can be utilized to perform Pre-Test Actions. The behavior of these threads is exactly like a normal Thread Group element. The difference is that these type of threads **execute before the test proceeds to the executing of regular Thread Groups**.

Or under [Once Only Logic Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)

> process the controller(s) inside it only once per Thread, and pass over any requests under it during further iterations through the test plan.